# java.lang.NullPointerException when using getClass().getResource() to load an image

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception, classpath

I'm attempting to load an Image (leftStanding.png) using the following line:

```
spriteLeft[0] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/images/characters/" + characterType + "/leftStanding.png")).getImage();
```

where `characterType` is (at the moment) `"mainCharacterMale"`. However, I'm getting a NullPointerException at that line. Using Netbeans, the file path for the image is `ProjectFolder/src/resources/images/characters/mainCharacterMale/leftStanding.png`. Oddly enough, earlier in the program I load a text file in a very similar fashion, with the path to that being `ProjectFolder/src/resources/saveData/SaveFile1.txt`, and there's no errors with that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't do it like this. Your resource folder should be along the src folder, not inside of it. And then you can get your image with `ImageIO.read(new File ("./resources/images/.../yourimage.png"))`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I switched it to that method, reading in the saveFile still works, but I'm getting the same error as before (in terms of reading in the image). Now the file path is `ProjectFolder/resources/images/characters/mainCharacterMale/leftStanding.png`